# "What our dreams mean" vs "what our dreams meant."

Tags: tense-agreement

> If we could actually find out what our dreams **mean**, wouldn't that be great?
>
> If we could actually find out what our dreams **meant**, wouldn't that be great?

Now.
I was reading Stephen King's "The Stand" the other day, and I came across a line that read, *"If I said I **like** doing something...(I don't remember), it would be a lie."*

So, going by that, there's no problem whether I use *Mean*, or *Meant* there in the above given examples, right? 
And, they both mean the same, right?

Comment: Context, context, context! In some contexts you *must* say *meant* and in others you *must* say *mean*, because they have different referents; but in yet other contexts you may say either.

Comment: Do you mean Stephen King's _The Stand_?

Comment: In these examples I would say that the first sentence refers to knowing what dreams mean in general-- it's about finding out what any dream means. The second sentence would refer to knowing what some specific dreams (that the speaker has already had) mean.

Comment: @J.R., yup
Sorry.

Comment: @Upper_Case 
 
Okay. What about this sentence. "If we bought that apartment, we would have a place to party whenever we want/wanted.

Comment: @StoneyB, what about the sentence in the above comment?

Comment: If i use wanted, wouldn't that mean, i wanted a place to party, but i might not anymore.
And If i use want, won't that mean my current want to have a place to party? @StoneyB

Comment: @lekon I think that you will find both versions of that sentence in use among native speakers but that the form using the present-tense "want" is easier to justify grammatically. The past-tense form shouldn't apply to a description of a future conditional event, as far as I know, but I don't think that there would be any ambiguity of meaning in this example based on common (not necessarily correct) use.

Comment: @lekon You could make a case that using "wanted" indicates that at some point in the future will have allowed the speaker to party whenever he or she wanted between buying the apartment and that future time. If so, the sentence as written is unclear, but whether you intended that or not the sentence would almost certainly be interpreted by a listener/reader as if you had used "want".

Comment: I couldn't locate any such sentence with [I like](https://books.google.com/books?id=UbfnTcmkaKkC&printsec=frontcover&dq=the+stand+Stephen+King&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjs6cGCz-bMAhXHQiYKHdebDAsQ6AEIGzAA#v=snippet&q=%22I%20like%22%20&f=false) in the Stephen King novel  but Google is not perfect.

Comment: @AlanCarmack, there was a sentence in the revised edition, where he wrote about why they were releasing the revised edition of the book. And how in the previous book they had had to leave out certain parts.

Comment: @lekon What is the ISBN of the version of *The Stand* in which  you found this sentence? Also, your comment does not make sense. They "left out" stuff in the previous book, or they left out stuff in the revised edition?

Answer (score 1):

As @StoneyB points out there are times when both can mean the same and other times when they may mean something different.

Aside from the obvious, present (mean) vs past (meant), one way to look at which to use is whether one is still *holding on* to whatever dream it is (the dream could be literal or figurative), or its relevance.

> Every graduating class has ***dreams*** which ***mean*** the world to them.
>
> The graduating class of 1969 had ***dreams*** which ***meant*** the world to them.
>   Dreams of social change and world peace.
>   Then they got jobs, had families, and daily practicalities overtook those dreams.

In general, using the present (mean) would probably be understood to have more current relevance to the speaker than using the past (meant). Consider the difference between

> A year ago I had a dream and I think it meant
>   A year ago I had a dream and I think it *(still)* means

In your examples, the two sentences appear to be interchangeable since it might always be nice to know the meaning of one's dreams whether currently relevant or not.